# Concatenate HTML with Django variable in HTML Template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a question which could help me a bit in my project.
I would like to know if it's possible to concatenate an HTML input action with a Django variable ?

For example :

```
<form method='POST' action='/BirthCertificate/BirthCertificate_PDF/'+ {{birthcertificate.id}}> {% csrf_token %}
```

In order to get : `/BirthCertificate/BirthCertificate_PDF/12/`

Where 12, for example refers to the last `ID` created in my table.
Then, I have a function which takes this id number and makes some things because I know the useful row :

From **views.py file** :

```
def BirthCertificate_PDF(request, id) :

    birthcertificate = get_object_or_404(BirthCertificate, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'BC_raw.html', {"birthcertificate" : birthcertificate})
```

From **urls.py file** :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil$', views.BirthCertificate_Home, name="home"),
    url(r'^formulaire$', views.BirthCertificate_Form, name = "form"),
    url(r'^formulaire_traite/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.BirthCertificate_Resume, name="treated"),
    url(r'^BirthCertificate_PDF/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.BirthCertificate_PDF, name="PDF")
]
```

I think my question is really ugly but it could work if I can concatenate both elements.

Thank you if you have advices,

Comment: What did you get when you tried it?..

Comment: I think that the general answer is that `{{var}}` works anywhere in Django Template rendering, except inside `{% stuff %}` or nested in an outer `{{...}}`. There is no `+` concatenation operator, it's just direct textual substitution of `{{var}}` by the value of var. View the page source your view's output in your web browser to see what is happening!. However, for this *particular* usage, there are good reasons to use `{% url ...%}` instead, as per Daniel Roseman's answer below.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I searched as answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be concatenating at all, neither should you be hard-coding the path. You should use the `{% url %}` tag.

```
<form action="{% url "PDF" birthcertificate.id %}">
```

Comment: Thank you ! Now I understand how I have to use `{% url %}`